# Show chapter in main toc but not in parttoc

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

Is it possible not to display the last chapter in the second parttoc ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0} 

\begin{document}
\doparttoc
\tableofcontents

\part{Part 1}
\parttoc
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}

\part{Part 2}
\parttoc
\chapter{Chapter 3}
\chapter{Chapter 4}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried my luck and got the exact opposite of what you wanted with chapter 4 missing in toc but not in parttoc. I used the [tocvsec2 package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocvsec2) and with `\settocdepth{part}` bevor the chapter 4 I got that result, because it changes the depth of the toc at a specific point in a document. So in theory shouldn't it be possible to write a macro doing the exact same thing, but just for parttoc instead of toc? Unfortunately I have no experience with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind changing the insides of `minitoc` a little you can do this. I'm not sure this answer is a particularly good one because

- The `minitoc` documentation mentions that the package has been substantially reworked at least once, so there's a lot of reason to doubt this solution will work with older versions of the package. (And of course, if future versions change  how `minitoc`'s `\PTC@test` command is used, it might not with those either.)
- The `\skipcontents` and `\readcontents` commands I'm about to define don't quite work as intuitively as I think they ought. (E.g., the caveat at the end of this answer)

Consequently, a better idea may be to just switch and use [`etoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc). If you're absolutely set on `minitoc`, though, here is a sort-of answer.

Since minitoc reads through the `.toc` file and picks out relevant commands like `\contentsline` and puts them in their own partial toc (.ptc) files. You can (sort of) get what you want by redefining the command `\PTC@test`, which minitoc uses to test for relevance, so that it also tests whether you've told it to ignore `\contentsline`s. You can then add commands to the `.toc` file which don't do anything, but which `minitoc` recognizes as switching the relevance of `\contentsline` on or off.

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
    \usepackage{minitoc}
    \newif\ifignorecontents
    \newcommand\skipcontents{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\ignorecontentstrue}}
    \newcommand\readcontents{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\ignorecontentsfalse}}
    \makeatletter
    %Mostly copied from minitoc documentation p.357, ll.4257-4271
    \long\def\PTC@test#1#2#3#4#5#6\PTC@{%  
     \ifx#1\ignorecontentstrue \ignorecontentstrue\else
     \ifx#1\ignorecontentsfalse \ignorecontentsfalse\else
     \ifx#1\contentsline
          \ifignorecontents\else
            \let\mtc@string\string
            \PTC@contentsline{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
            \let\mtc@string\relax
          \fi
     \else\ifx#1\@input
           \edef\PTC@list{\PTC@list#2\relax}%
     \else\ifx#1\partend
            \immediate\closeout\tf@mtc
             \immediate\openout\tf@mtc=\jobname.mtc
     \else\ifx#1\partbegin
              \addtocounter{ptc}{-1}%
     \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
     \ifeof\@inputcheck\expandafter\PTC@toc
     \else\expandafter\PTC@read\fi}%
    \makeatother
    \begin{document}
```

And then around the chapter you don't want

```
    \chapter{Chapter 3}

    \skipcontents %exclude from part's toc

    \chapter{Chapter 4}

    \readcontents %start including again

    \chapter{Chapter 5}
```

But if you have something like

```
    \chapter{Chapter 3}
    \section{3.1}
    \section{3.2}
    \skipcontents
    \section{3.3}
    \chapter{Chapter 4} 
    \section{4.1}
    \section{4.2}
    \readcontents
    \section{4.3}
```

you'll get a line for section 4.3 under chapter 3 in the partial toc.

Answer (score 2):

After a look at the minitoc package it is possible to put a bound on the parttoc with `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\partbegin}`. Unfortunately this just works for the last chapters of a part, but not for chapters inbetween.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0} 

\begin{document}
\doparttoc
\tableofcontents

\part{Part 1}
\parttoc
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}

\part{Part 2}

\parttoc
\chapter{Chapter 3}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\partbegin}
\chapter{Chapter 4}
\end{document}`
```