# Delete section* from minitoc

Tags: minitoc

I have this problem: as you can see

[image: No Prefazione alla Prima Parte]

I'd like to delete "`\section*{Prefazione alla Prima Parte}`" from `chapter 1`'s minitoc. How could I do? Does a MWE serve?
Thank you and Best Regards

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[tight, italian]{minitoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\setcounter{chapter}{-1}

\setcounter{section}{-1}

\newcommand*{\arabicdec}[1]{\the\numexpr\value{#1}-1\relax}
%\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\arabicdec{chapter}}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabicdec{section}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}


\begin{document}

\title{\color{red}{\Huge{\textbf{ALGEBRA LINEARE}}}}
\author{\color{blue}{\Huge{\textbf{???}}}}
\date{27 Febbraio 2021 $-$ xx Mese Anno}

\frontmatter

\maketitle

\dominitoc

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section*{PREFAZIONE GENERALE}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}PREFAZIONE GENERALE}

\mainmatter

\chapter{NOTAZIONI PRELIMINARI}
\minitoc %\minilof\minilot
\mtcskip
\pagestyle{plain}

\section{??}

\newpage

\part{\huge\color{red}{FONDAMENTI DELL'ALGEBRA LINEARE}}

\section*{Prefazione alla Prima Parte}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Prefazione alla Prima Parte}
\Large{Inserire una Prefazione}

\chapter{One}
\minitoc %\minilof\minilot
\mtcskip

\section{One.One}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, we need a MWE.

Comment: Why do you have `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Prefazione alla Prima Parte}`?

Comment: Because I want that "Prefazione alla Prima Parte" is only in \tableofcontentes and not in minitoc of chapter 0.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197066/107497, you need to tell minitoc that the `part` has begun.  So add `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\partbegin}` before the `\part` command.

By the way, you shouldn't add color/sizing/capitalization to your title/part/chapter/section commands.  If you're wanting that styling, you should modify those commands (eg with the `titlesec` package).